# How to resolve OperationalError: near "(": syntax error in sqldf python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqldf, lead

I am running a simple query on pandas-dataframe:

```
l="""select LEAD(quarter_num,1) OVER (ORDER BY col1 , col2, col3) AS next from df"""
out=ps.sqldf(l, locals())

Error:OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Is `Lead` function not supported in `sqldf`. I want to execute sql code in python and so have to restrict myself to use sqldf and LEAD.

Any help?